# MySQL Statement syntax error but extraced from old source code where it worked 10 Years Ago

Tags: mysql, java1.4

I have the Following SQL Query I want to use in my mySQL Database:

`SELECT case when COLUMN1 is NULL then 'unknown' else COLUMN1 , COLUMN2, COLUMN3, COLUMN4 FROM TABLE1`

I get this error message:
`SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax;`

I am using the following mySQL Version:

[image]

My Question is not only where is the Syntax error, but also how can I have some 10 year old java code which was connected to a mySQL database too and the Query above worked.

So is there a possibility that the Syntax of the SQL Queries changed over the Years and are there some settings to get back this "compatibility", because I had to change a lot of Queries in the old java software in order to get them all to run

Comment: Oracle has apparently decided to take old MySQL documentation off-line so I can't share a link but according to my local copy `CASE` was introduced in MySQL 3.23.3 and `END` has never been optional. It's just not possible that such code ever worked. You blame Java: is it because you do some post-processing you haven't shared?

Comment: Hi, I started the old application: `com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax;` So no post processing.

Can you maybe give me a hint how the Query syntax is right ?

Comment: 1) Sorry, I don't understand how getting a syntax errors proves what SQL query is actually executed 2) It's right if you add the `END` clause, it isn't if you don't. I doubt that has changed.